# The code below works in Windows but not in Mac. Error in Redim Preserve

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, macos

The code below works in excel for windows, but not in excel for mac.
It gives error 9 subscript out of range.
When I run the code in my Windows machine, everything is fine.
When I try to run it in a Mac with excel for Mac then I get the error message in the procedure below and the line added at the end of this post.

```
Sub GetUniqueID(aFirstArray() As Variant, DataUniqueID As Variant)

Dim aUniqueArray() As Variant
Dim lngCountFirst As Long
Dim lngCountUnique As Long
Dim bolFoundIt As Boolean
Dim strOne As String
Dim strTwo As String

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer



Dim ColIndex As Integer
ColIndex = 1

'// Redim with one element, empty at this point.//
ReDim aUniqueArray(0)

'// loop thru ea element in our first array. (This is our outer loop)//
For lngCountFirst = LBound(aFirstArray()) To UBound(aFirstArray())

'// ensure that we flag as False at the start of ea loop//
bolFoundIt = False

'// In a secondary, inner loop, we can build the unique array, only //
'// adding items that have not already been added. //
For lngCountUnique = LBound(aUniqueArray()) To UBound(aUniqueArray())

'// For ea element in our unique array, see if it matches the //
'// current element being looked at in our frist array. If we //
'// find a match, mark our flag/boolean and exit the inner loop.//
'// On the other hand, if no match is found after every element //
'// in our unique array is looked at, then bolFoundIt will still//
'// be False. //
If aUniqueArray(lngCountUnique) = aFirstArray(lngCountFirst, ColIndex) Then
bolFoundIt = True
Exit For
End If
Next lngCountUnique

'// Now if bolFound is still False, then we didn't find a match, so //
'// we'll add it to the last available element in our unique array //
'// and add another empty element to the unique array for the next //
'// round... Note the use of Redim Preserve, so that we don't //
'// lose the values already added. //
If Not bolFoundIt Then
aUniqueArray(UBound(aUniqueArray())) = aFirstArray(lngCountFirst, ColIndex)
ReDim Preserve aUniqueArray(UBound(aUniqueArray()) + 1)
End If

Next lngCountFirst

'// Now after we're all done, we left our unique array with one //
'// extra/unused element. We'll drop/kill the extra element here. //
ReDim Preserve aUniqueArray(UBound(aUniqueArray()) - 1)



ReDim DataUniqueID(1 To UBound(aUniqueArray()) + 1, 1 To UBound(aFirstArray, 2))

For i = 1 To UBound(DataUniqueID)
    DataUniqueID(i, 1) = aUniqueArray(i - 1)
    
Next i

For i = 1 To UBound(DataUniqueID)
    
    For j = 2 To UBound(aFirstArray)
    If DataUniqueID(i, 1) = aFirstArray(j, 1) Then
            DataUniqueID(i, 5) = DataUniqueID(i, 5) & "," & aFirstArray(j, 5)
            DataUniqueID(i, 7) = DataUniqueID(i, 7) & "," & aFirstArray(j, 7)
            DataUniqueID(i, 12) = DataUniqueID(i, 12) & "," & aFirstArray(j, 12)
            DataUniqueID(i, 14) = DataUniqueID(i, 14) & "," & aFirstArray(j, 14)
    End If
    Next j
Next i



End Sub
```

The line with error is this one:
`ReDim Preserve aUniqueArray(UBound(aUniqueArray()) - 1)`
Any ideas?

--Edit2---
this sub is called from another sub:

```
Dim Data() As Variant
'more code between
'but nothing that changes the dimensions of Data. Just assigning values loops etc

'***** Create an array with the Data for faster operation
Data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CDR").Range("A1:V" & LastRow).Value

'more code here

 'Test the conditional compiler constant #Mac
#If Mac Then
'I am a Mac
                        'Define Folder Path
    'Function to create folder if it not exists in the Microsoft Office Folder
    'Ron de Bruin : 13-July-2020
    Dim OfficeFolder As String
    Dim TestStr As String

    OfficeFolder = MacScript("return POSIX path of (path to desktop folder) as string")
    OfficeFolder = Replace(OfficeFolder, "/Desktop", "") & "Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/Script #1 output - " & FilenameDateStamp
    On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(OfficeFolder & "*", vbDirectory)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TestStr = vbNullString Then
        MkDir OfficeFolder
        'You can use this msgbox line for testing if you want
        'MsgBox "You find the new folder in this location :" & PathToFolder
    End If

                    '14. SAVE OUTPUT FILES part 2 - save first set of output files
                    ' File #1 & 2 --Save the current spreadsheet in it's entirety, as a new Excel and CSV version named dynamically as
                    '"For import - Mojo CallDetailParsed_yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm.xlsx"
                    '(and a copy in .csv format)
                    
' copies a worksheet into a new file and saves it onto desktop
    
    Dim newWB As Workbook
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CDR").Select
    Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CDR").Copy Before:=newWB.Sheets(1)

'this saves the new workbook
    With newWB
    '.SaveAs FileName:="[FONT=arial][COLOR=black]Macintosh HD:Users:robertandres[/COLOR][/FONT]:Desktop:TEST.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    .SaveAs FileName:=OfficeFolder & "/For import - Mojo CallDetailParsed_" & FilenameDateStamp, FileFormat:=51
    .Saved = True
    .SaveAs FileName:=OfficeFolder & "/For import - Mojo CallDetailParsed_" & FilenameDateStamp, FileFormat:=22
    .Close
    End With



                    '15. SAVE OUTPUT FILES part 2 - save second set of output files
                    'File #2 & 3  which is the same as the above but contains only columns A, F, L, V
                    '"For import - Mojo phone tags from calldetail Parsed_yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm.xslx"
                    '(and a copy in .csv format)
                    
' copies a worksheet into a new file and saves it onto desktop
    
    Dim newWB2 As Workbook
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CDR").Select
    Set newWB2 = Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CDR").Copy Before:=newWB2.Sheets(1)
                    newWB2.Sheets("CDR").Columns("M:U").Delete
                    newWB2.Sheets("CDR").Columns("G:K").Delete
                    newWB2.Sheets("CDR").Columns("B:E").Delete
                    
'this saves the new workbook
    With newWB2
    '.SaveAs FileName:="[FONT=arial][COLOR=black]Macintosh HD:Users:robertandres[/COLOR][/FONT]:Desktop:TEST.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    .SaveAs FileName:=OfficeFolder & "/For import - Mojo phone tags from calldetail Parsed" & FilenameDateStamp, FileFormat:=51
    .Saved = True
    .SaveAs FileName:=OfficeFolder & "/For import - Mojo phone tags from calldetail Parsed" & FilenameDateStamp, FileFormat:=22
    .Close
    End With


#Else
'I am Windows
'code for windows that works ok
#End If

'prevent flickering and make faster
Application.ScreenUpdating = True



Dim DataUniqueID() As Variant
Call GetUniqueID(Data, DataUniqueID)
```

Comment: What does `UBound(aUniqueArray())` show when stopped on error and moving the cursor over it? I do not think it is something related to MacOS...

Comment: What is `aFirstArray` ?  Where does it come from?  Agree with @FaneDuru - there's nothing Mac-specific about basic array operations.

Comment: @FaneDuru I don't have access to a mac right Now. I will update as soon as possible. It works in windows

Comment: Does it work **on the same workbook**?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, same workbook. I use separate code for win and mac to save results as workbooks. But only to save. Something like `#If Mac Then ... #else ... #endif` . I
was troubleshooting that and when problems with that were resolved, that error comes from this different sub.

Comment: Please try testing what I suggested in my first comment (when having access to the laptop)? I mean, what value does `UBound(aUniqueArray())` when stopped on error and move the cursor over it? I am afraid that you will be surprised... And you/we should check **why** such a value...

Comment: @FaneDuru  its 0...

Comment: And how to redim at -1, preserving values...? You must check why is it zero. Try running the code line by line, ptessing F8 and see what's happening...

Comment: @FaneDuru The same file is working in windows. Unless Ubound and ReDim Preserve works differently in Mac the error is caused by the code I included in the edit. It is the only mac specific code up to there. It runs directly before the Sub GetUniqueID is called. I am sorry for the messed up code in there. I was just trying to ensure the csv file is created but instead i got the error message.

Comment: I cannot get you. Your code fails **NOT because of "Ubound and ReDim Preserve working way"**. It fails because `UBound(aUniqueArray()) -1` **for a zero array `UBound` does not make sense in VBA (Windows or MacOS)**. If you do not do what I suggested above, to see **what else** produces that array, we cannot help, because we do not have acces to your specific data processed by the code.

Comment: @FaneDuru `UBound(aUniqueArray()) -1` gets a zero or fails **only** in Mac, not Windows. Therefore, it is the consequence of a different problem.  That problem must start at the Mac specific code. I added that code to the question. Also, I am trying to do what you suggested before and in the meanwhile I try to make my question more accurate. Your help is appreciated, either way.

Comment: A single issue to be clarified: Are you sure that in case of Window `UBound(aUniqueArray())` is zero **in the same circumstances**? I am not... Did you test this aspect, or only you suppose?

Comment: @FaneDuru I am assuming because it works. But since you asked, I tested it, and it is 309, as expected. Same file... But since I import a csv file in mac then maybe the import does not work in mac. That would explain the results. Off for more testing.

Comment: And what do you understand from that? Isn't it extremely clear that **`UBound(aUniqueArray()) -1` fails NOT because working on MAC, it fails because ``UBound(aUniqueArray())` is zero**. And it is zero only on MAC. Not because of MAC... Arrays works the same in both OS.  So, you must understand **WHY**! I am afraid you can do it only following my above suggestion: Run the code line by line, and see why the array is not filled in MacOS...

Comment: How `aFirstArray()` is loaded? Where are you taking from? Place a testing line: `Debug.Print ubound(aFirstArray): stop` at the beginning of the function code and check what does it show in `Immediate Window`. Isn't it empty already?

Answer (score 1):

I created the macro for windows, and then it had to work also in Mac.
I did not have access to mac so in mind everything was tested but only in windows, not in mac.
The problem was that above the code in the question, I was importing data. The code to import data was not working for mac. When I fixed that code, everything worked fine.
Assumptions and poor testing was the problem. I solved this when I got full access to a mac.
Thanks @faneduru